# GIS 3.12.2 Error after installing; Could not load qgis_app.ddl

Tags: qgis, error, windows

After installing QGis, I got the following error: [image]

[image]

Does anyone have a solution to get QGis working?

[image]

Comment: I think a simple google search will throw up several possible solutions.

Comment: See my answer here: https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/357479/122597

Comment: @Stefan I looked at your answer in the other thread and have tried the same approach several times, by deleting all the folders of older and different versions of QGis in my /program files & /program files (x86) of my (C:) drive, but I still get the same errors. Are there any other folders I should delete besides the standard OSGeo and QGis folder in the program files folder

Comment: maybe the QGIS folders in "Users/<your username>/App Data/Local" and "...Roaming". (The App Data directory is hidden by default.)